# Adding Comments Section To Posts In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

I am trying to add a comments section to posts on my web applications but getting an error when saving the comment

I have been following a tutorial to add a comments section to my posts and have been modifying as I go to work with my app. I am still relatively new to rails and I am still learning. I understand what the error message is telling me, but I am unsure as to how to proceed

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @comment = 
    @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))   
  end

end
```

Microposts Contoller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user, :upvote, :downvote, only: 
[:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, :upvote, :downvote,   only: 
 :destroy, allow_destroy: true


 def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    @maximum_length = Micropost.validators_on(  :content, 
    :headline).first.options[:maximum]
     if @micropost.save
       flash[:success] = "Article Posted"
     redirect_to root_url
     else
       @feed_items = []
     render 'articles/home'
     end
 end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || current_user
  end

 def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
 end

 private

 def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :headline)
 end

 def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
 end

end
```

Comments Form being rendered on post:

```
<%= form_for([@micropost, @micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <br>

  <p>
    <%= current_user.name %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <br>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
   </p>

 <% end %>
```

Comments Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :micropost
end
```

Microposts Model:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_votable

  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :headline, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 5000 }

end
```

Tables:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "body"
    t.bigint "microposts_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "micropost_id"
    t.index ["microposts_id"], name: 
    "index_comments_on_microposts_id"
  end

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "headline"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: 
    "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
     t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
   end
```

The form is being rendered on the micropost show view. I can see the form fine.

When I press to save the comment on the post I get an error stating `undefined method comments for nil:NilClass` and it highlights the Comments controller and the line `@comment = @micropost.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))`

I know there probably should a method somewhere for comments. The tutorial I watched didn't add anything like that. So I unsure do I need to modify some existing code, or do I need to add a method somewhere called comments?

Comment: Your problem, as the error states, is that `@micropost` is `nil` and `nil` doesn't respond to `comments`. Clearly, `Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])` is returning nil. Which means `params[:id]` is `nil` or holds a value that is not an `id` of a `Micropost`.

Comment: What are your params coming into the comments_controller?

Answer (score 1):

where is the form to create comments, you are not sending the parameter params [: id], and with this parameter you are looking for the @ micropost .. you must send the id in that form, a quick solution could be

```
<% = f.hidden_field: id, value: @ micropost.id%>
```

in the comment creation form

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the answers you all gave pointed me in the right direction. I wasn't actually passing an proper id. Instead of `@micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:id])` it should have been `@micropost = Micropost.find_by(id: params[:micropost_id])`

Many thanks all for getting me there.